# Passing Argument to main.scala.html

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, scala-2.10

Problem **(which works)**:

I am using Play 2.1.x version in my application. My application has a static header/toolbar which has SignIn/SignOut links. Instead of repeating status header html code in all the templates, I created that in main.scala.html template. Now to change SignIn/SignOut status, I need to pass an argument to main.scala.html.
  If I am right this is the parent template for all the templates we use in play, so if we add any argument to main template, it has to be provided by the child templates like for e.g index, login etc (you name it)

So far I am able to do this by creating an implicit def in a trait and let controller implement the trait like this (mixing composition...)

```
class ApplicationController extends Controller with ImplicitSession{

}

trait ImplicitSession {
implicit def status(implicit session: play.api.mvc.Session): Boolean = {
session.get("session") match {
  case None => false
  case _ => true
 }
}
```

and let my all the other controller extends ApplicationController instead of only play Controller

```
object LoginController extends ApplicationController{...}
```

Now My templates arguments look like this...

Main Template

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit status : Boolean)
```

other templates like login...

```
@(message: String)(implicit status : Boolean)
```

**This works Fine** but I am not happy with the solution because it force me to pass this extra implicit parameter to all my templates

**I really want to avoid passing this implicit parameter to my all child templates**

because I feel this is a redundant code and indeed not a good programming practice. So Looks like I didn't get this concept clear in my mind

Also compiler force me to put Action{ **implicit request =>** to all the controller I am creating otherwise it just throw an compilation error

I checked the sample code provided in the play bundle, they are good but my doubt of the flow is not clear..

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **I really want to avoid passing this implicit parameter to my all child templates**

The answer is that it is not possible to avoid (sadly).

[Here's an excellent blog describing this by James Roper](http://jazzy.id.au/default/2012/10/26/passing_common_state_to_templates_in_play_framework.html) (who is a Play Framework developer at Typesafe).

I use this pattern as well but I have preferred to use the name `ApplicationContext` for the case class that I pass along to all my views.

```
case class ApplicationContext(user: Option[User], moreData: SomeData)

trait ApplicationController extends Controller {
  implicit def context[A](implicit request: Request[A]): ApplicationContext = {
    // Find all necessary data needed
    ...
    ApplicationContext(user, data)
  }
}
```

And my views then typically takes the following parameters (including `Lang` for use of i18n):

```
@(message: String)(implicit lang: Lang, context: ApplicationContext)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Later I realize that there are many more parameter that I need at the root context and actually did something similar like what you did. Looks like creating a implicit variable might work good with static data but doesn't hold good for dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid that situation I would suggest not having every page use main.scala.html.

There are a few ways you can do this.  One is through concatenation since your views are really just returning concatenated strings to be wrapped by a Result (Ok,BadRequest,etc).

```
def getStuff = Action { Ok(header.scala.html(someData) + stuff.scala.html()) }
```

However that's kinda ugly.

The second way would be to send as little data on initial page load as possible and use AJAX requests to progressively enhance the view.

// Server Side

```
def getStuff = Action { Ok(stuff.scala.html()) }

def getMoarStuff = Action { Ok(moarStuff.scala.html(someData)) }
```

// Client Side

```
$.ajax({
  method  : "GET",
  url     : "http://localhost:9000/moar/stuff",
  success : function() {
    console.log("got stuff");
  },
  failure:function() {
    console.log("failed");
  }
});
```

This is the premise and advantage of a [single page application](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).  You can accomplish this through rolling your own AJAX handlers (see above silliness) or using a JavaScript framework such as Backbone, Ember, or Angular.  Each have their own traits / advantages / disadvantages, but the important thing to understand is that they are each quite usable with Play.

Comment: Jason- I agree with your approach, In fact I am using Angular now (replacing it from existing Knockout). Play fits well with all these front js api because it provides a pure separation between backend and front end (pure web service framework and can be called from anywhere not limited to templates), My only intention to is to understand how can I do it well using implicit mechanism of scala with proper hierarchical structure if exist.. I like your approach of having separate main for each module. Thanks much!